# Dynamically build a JSON object with an array inside in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to build a json out of an array and send it through a socket to a java application and open it there. I have somehting like

```
array = ["a","b","c"]

{
  "events":[
        {"id":array[0], "name":"bla1"},
        {"id":array[1], "name":"bla2"}
   ],
   "name": "bla"
}
```

I have try to use concatenation to no success. How can I do it?

Comment: Show us the code that sends the data through the socket, and the code that opens it on the other end.

Comment: Concatenation _of what_?? Also, have a look a at the built-in [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
o ={
    "events":[{"id": item, "name": "blah%s" %(index + 1)}
              for index, item in enumerate(array)],
   "name": "bla"
}

print(o)
# {'events': [{'id': 'a', 'name': 'blah1'}, {'id': 'b', 'name': 'blah2'}, {'id': 'c', 'name': 'blah3'}], 'name': 'bla'}
```

Comment: this did what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @andresviena, awesome! Can you please accept it as an answer so other people know and I get those sweet sweet stackoverflow points?